# Firestore: How to deal with multiple writes on a single document limit(1per second) for the case of "Liked Count" on a Post

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How would we implement the `post liked count` feature like in Instagram in Firestore while not being affected by the write limit?

Let's say the social app being built is very popular and a famous user with millions of followers posts a post. Naturally, in a short span of time, many of the followers would be liking the post. The `likes` are not a problem since they are a top level collection. And the limit does not concern us here since every follower is updating their own specific document.

However for the `like_count` field, all these users would be trying to update this same document at the same time. This would be problematic because of the limitation. And the like count would be wrong.

I learned about "Sharding" or ["Distributed Counter"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) which is basically distrubuting the like count to many documents and linearly divides the limit. However this is not a kind of solution I am looking for since it does not scale well and needs too much of an architecture for generating such a simple number.

Does this Limitation mean, an app like Instagram, Twitter, Facebook, Snapchat, TikTok can never have Firestore as the backend? Or are there some smart strategies which overcome this limitations.

Comment: How is it that distributed counters don't scale well?  That solution was designed explicitly to scale well, and is the recommended solution.  That is basically your only choice if you want scalable counts stored in Firestore, unless you want to store your likes somewhere else, complicating things even further.  If you want a shortcut, you can implement that pattern with Firebase Extensions, but it is still essentially the same thing: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-counter

Comment: @DougStevenson How will I decide the number of shards which ensures that I am not hitting the limit? Also for some popular users number of shards need to be more than normal users. It would be overkill to use same number of shards for everyuser. If I decide to make this num of shards dynamic(proportional to followers count), I need to watch for follower count of every user. I realize this is not a "decision made limitation" but a physical one with the current architecture. Do you think you guys can implement a new data type specifically for the "count" case which handles multiple writes well?

Comment: Simple math - decide what your max like rate should be, then create enough shards to handle that capacity, given the max sustained write of a single document is 1/second.  You really don't have a better option if you want to keep "live" counts in Firestore. If this really isn't going to work for you, you can always use another type of data store that can do what you want.  Be careful about overthinking things, and also be aware that any solution that works at scale is going to cost some combination of time and money.  There are no simple workarounds to systems that must operate at cloud scale.

Comment: *This would be problematic because of the limitation* - what limitation? Have you explored [Real Time Database Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) or [Firestore Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)? Do you have 1,000,000 users? If not, how many do you have and then what percentage of them would all hit the 'Like' button at the same time? As Doug said don't over think it - project reasonable usage.

Comment: Hi Doug and Jay, thanks for your feedback. one last question: Is there any downsides for just keeping "counts" in Realtime DB seperate from the rest of our DB in firestore? So that we won't be affected by the write limitation.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution can be to have a row for each like and schedule a function (at least every minute) for count and update the main post.

Comment: Thanks, this came to my mind but this is a very consuming task both performance wise and cost wise in my opinion for just gathering a count.